# How to get all parameters of figure() function?

Tags: bokeh

How to get parameters of figure function (http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.Figure)

I have checked the documentation of

1. bokeh.models.plots.Plot (http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot)
2. bokeh.models.widget.Widgets
3. and source code https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/bokeh

found no complete list of parameters of figure along the inheritance chain,

for example , how can I find parameter

```
x_axis_label='datetime'
```

from source code/ documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

All of these parameters are now fully documented, see keyword args for:

### http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.figure

As of 0.10, there are a handful of "kwarg" parameters that we have not yet been able to automate the documentation of. There is no good way to find them programmatically, but you can see all of them here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/plotting.py#L41

Anything else is a standard property, that will show up in the automated reference docs. But the list of "extra" parameters boils down to:

```
x_range
y_range

x_axis_type
y_axis_type

x_minor_ticks
y_minor_ticks

x_axis_location
y_axis_location

x_axis_label
y_axis_label
```

If you could make a GitHub issue to request better docs automation around these parameters it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the link is now here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/plotting/figure.py ?